# How do I get excel to evaluate the result of a formula as a formula?

Tags: reference, formula

I am creating a spreadsheet where a user can pick different options to filter data. I pull the options together into a formula using concat &. so the result looks like a formula. I gave the formula a name but when I use the name excel just show the completed formula as a result. I want excel to evaluate the resulting formula as a formula.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eszy1.png)

If I do a copy and past values then excel will recognize the formula.

I have tried various functions but nothing seems to work.